# How to insert values from if function into an array with openpyxl in python?

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, insert, openpyxl

Here I'm trying to run through an excel file in columns A and D. I'm trying to create a one column array of values from column A where a condition for Column D is true. I'm not sure how to have the corresponding values from column A be input into the array. I'm also very new to coding and don't know a lot of what I'm doing, any advice is appreciated.

```
for cell in clf['D']: #iterates through column D
if cell.value == 0:
    #insert into empty array corresponding values from column A 
    np.insert(array,0,clf['A'])
else:
    pass`
```

My output is this

`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Cell'`

Comment: Make sure your code is properly indented -- also some information about the output you are getting with your current code will help people work on the problem.

Comment: Code is indented in python. I know what I've written is wrong, I just don't know how to have the if function run through Column D, and at points where if is true, input the value from Column A into the array using numpy insert. My output is this

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Cell'

Comment: When you say: 
> I just don't know how to have the if function run through Column D
Are you referring to if `cell.value == 0:` from your python code?